# Cannot login as administrator

Tags: 14.04

when trying to log in with my old user account (administrator) it brings me back to the log in screen. I don't get any type of error it's just does as if it's loading the desktop and then goes back to log in screen in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried logging on a non-graphical screen (type `CTRL-ALT-F1`)?

Comment: yes but it does not make effect

Comment: What does "does not make effect" mean? What happens after you type your correct userid/password on a Ctrl-Alt-F1 screen? Is your `~/.bashrc` mis-owned, mis-protected or broken?

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a few different reasons. The three most common, that come to mind, are: change of display manager, display variable, and choice of desktop when trying to login (you may have installed more than one Desktop Environment).

To test to see if it is in fact one of those three, boot the computer and when the login manager (unity-greeter) presents itself, type control-alt-F6.

```
Ctl-Alt-F6
```

This will take you to a textual console. You then should type the name of the admin account, and your password. If it will not allow you to login like this then you have an issue with your password or something else. If you do succeed in logging with the admin account this way than simply type

```
:~$ sudo reboot
```

or

```
:~$ exit
```

if you choose exit type control-alt-F7 to return to the unity-greeter.

Please give some feedback on this.

Comment: when i type sudo reboot it reboot my system and nothing else